# Tailing a named pipe in node.js

Tags: linux, node.js, socket.io

I'm using node-tail to read a file in linux and send it down to a socket.

node.js sending data read from a text file

```
var io = require('socket.io');
Tail = require('tail').Tail;


tail = new Tail("/tmp/test.txt");


io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

tail.on("line", function(data) {
  socket.emit('Message', { test: data });

});

});
```

Receiving side

```
var socket = io.connect();
  socket.on('Message', function (data) {

    console.log(data.test);

  });
```

This works but when I try to modify this part

```
tail = new Tail("/tmp/test.txt");
```

to this

```
tail = new Tail("/tmp/FIFOFILE");
```

I can't get any data from it.

Is there anyway to read a named pipe in linux? or a package that can read a named pipe?

Comment: I would think in theory this should work. Are you sure the process writing to the fifo has it open and is writing data when node opens it and starts reading? I wonder if there are edge cases around the state the fifo is in when node opens it.

Comment: `node-tail` uses `fs.watchFile` to check if the file size has increased since the last iteration (and reopens the file to read the extra bytes when it has grown), which isn't going to work for named pipes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can get it to work in a silly way:

```
// app.js
process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.on('data', function(chunk) {
 console.log('D', chunk);
});
```

And start like this:

```
node app.js < /tmp/FIFOFILE
```

If I create a readable stream for the named pipe, it ends after having read the first piece of data written to the named pipe. Not sure why `stdin` is special.

Comment: nice, is there a way to read from the named pipe from within node.js code? fs.openSync(namedPipe) something something?

Comment: @AlexanderMills `fs.createReadStream(namedPipe)` works, I think there's a good chance that `fs.open/fs.openSync` would work as well.

Comment: @robertklep It does work but the stream closes immediately after receiving one set of data. If autoclose is set at false then only one buffer is received thus making this pointless... I haven't figured out how to maintain the stream opened and still receive data.

Comment: @ÉtienneBrouillard sounds like my "hack" got "fixed" in recent Node.js versions :(

Answer (score 1):

The OS will send an EOF when the last process finishes writing to the FIFO. If only one process is writing to the FIFO then you get an EOF when that process finishes writing its stuff. This EOF triggers Node to close the stream.

The trick to avoiding this is given by @JoshuaWalsh in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53492401/reliably-reading-from-a-fifo-in-nodejs), namely: you open the pipe yourself FOR READING AND WRITING - even though you have no intention of ever writing to it. This means that the OS sees that there is always at least one process writing to the file and so you never get the EOF.

So... just add in something like:

```
let fifoHandle = fs.open(fifoPath, fs.constants.O_RDWR,function(){console.log('FIFO open')});
```

You don't ever have to do anything with fifoHandle - just make sure it sticks around and doesn't get garbage collected.

In fact... in my case I was using createReadStream, and I found that simply adding the fs.constants.O_RDWR to this was enough (even though I have no intention of ever writing to the fifo.

```
let fifo = fs.createReadStream(fifoPath,{flags: fs.constants.O_RDWR});

fifo.on('data',function(data){
    console.log('Got data:'+data.toString());
}
```